# how can i force deadlock state in this code regarding "DINING PHILOSOPHERS PROBLEM"?

Tags: c, synchronization, deadlock, dining-philosopher, starvation

Having written the code regarding the dinner philosophers problem which avoids the deadlock, I now want to implement the code such that the deadlock occurs

I know that deadlock can occur if each of the philosophers is holding only one wand and waits to take the other one but I don't know how to proceed

The code is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define NUM_FIL 5
#define PENSA 2
#define AFFAMATO 1
#define MANGIA 0
#define SINISTRA (filosofi+4) % NUM_FIL
#define DESTRA (filosofi+1) % NUM_FIL

int stato[NUM_FIL];
int fil[NUM_FIL] = {0,1,2,3,4};

sem_t mutex;
sem_t F[NUM_FIL];

void schermoIniziale();
void verifica(int filosofi);
void prendeForchetta(int filosofi);
void lasciaForchetta(int filosofi);
void* filosofo(void* num);

void verifica(int filosofi){
    if (stato[filosofi] == AFFAMATO && stato[SINISTRA] == MANGIA && stato[DESTRA] != MANGIA) {
        stato[filosofi] = MANGIA;
        sleep(1);
        printf("Filosofo %d prende le forchette %d e %d\n", filosofi +1, SINISTRA+1, filosofi+1);
        printf("Filosofo %d MANGIA\n", filosofi+1);
        sem_post(&F[filosofi]);
    }
}

void lasciaForchetta(int filosofi){
    sem_wait(&mutex);
    stato[filosofi] = PENSA;
    printf("Filosofo %d lascia le forchette %d e %d \n",filosofi+1, SINISTRA+1, filosofi+1);
    printf("Filosofo %d PENSA\n", filosofi+1);
    verifica(SINISTRA);
    verifica(DESTRA);
    sem_post(&mutex);
}

void prendeForchetta(int filosofi){
    sem_wait(&mutex);
    stato[filosofi] = AFFAMATO;
    printf("Filosofo %d e' affamato\n", filosofi+1);
    verifica(filosofi);
    sem_post(&mutex);
    sem_wait(&F[filosofi]);
    sleep(1);
}

void* filosofo(void* num){
    while (true) {
        int* i = num;
        sleep(1);
        prendeForchetta(*i);
        sleep(1);
        lasciaForchetta(*i);
    }
}

int main(){
    int i;
    pthread_t fil_id[NUM_FIL];
    sem_init(&mutex,0,1);
    schermoIniziale();
    sleep(2);
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_FIL; i++){
        sem_init(&F[i],0,0);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_FIL; i++) {
        pthread_create(&fil_id[i], NULL, filosofo, &fil[i]);
        printf("Filosofo %d PENSA\n",i+1);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_FIL; i++){
        pthread_join(fil_id[i],NULL);
    }
}

void schermoIniziale(){
    printf("+-----------BENVENUTO------------+\n");
    printf("|   Dining philosophers problem  |\n");
    printf("+--------------------------------+\n\n");
}
```

Comment: `stato[SINISTRA] == MANGIA` must be `stato[SINISTRA] != MANGIA`.

Answer (score 0):

Your above implementation (after `stato[SINISTRA] == MANGIA` corrected to `stato[SINISTRA] != MANGIA`) always lets a philosopher take two forks at once. In order to make it possible that *each of the philosophers is holding only one* fork, we need to hold the state of each fork. I don't know what you intended to do with `sem_t F[NUM_FIL]`; let's use that as the fork states:

```
void lasciaForchetta(int filosofi)
{
    stato[filosofi] = PENSA;
    printf("Filosofo %d lascia le forchette %d e %d \n",
                     filosofi+1, SINISTRA+1, filosofi+1);
    sem_post(&F[SINISTRA]); // put down left hand fork
    sem_post(&F[filosofi]); // put down right hand fork
    printf("Filosofo %d PENSA\n", filosofi+1);
}

void prendeForchetta(int filosofi)
{
    stato[filosofi] = AFFAMATO;
    printf("Filosofo %d e' affamato\n", filosofi+1);
    sem_wait(&F[SINISTRA]); // take left hand fork
    printf("philosopher %d took first fork %d\n", filosofi+1, SINISTRA+1);
    /// sleep(1);   // put this in to enforce deadlock
    sem_wait(&F[filosofi]); // take right hand fork
    printf("philosopher %d took fork %d, eats\n", filosofi+1, filosofi+1);
    stato[filosofi] = MANGIA;
    sleep(1);
}
…
        sem_init(&F[i], 0, 1);  // all forks initially available
```

The insertion of a delay between a philosopher taking one fork and the other then makes it highly probable that a deadlock occurs.